# python countdown timer for a video game using the comand prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

> I'm currently working on a choose your own adventure game in python and I'm trying to set up a timer that after every 3-4 seconds your oxygen points deplete by 3, I will post the entire code for the game I would like help with which method of timer for it and where to put the timer. thank you for taking the time out of your day to help me

```
__Author__ = 'Mangle200/Tristan Lauzon'
import tkinter
from time import *
from random import *
import os,sys

def clear_screen():
    os.system('cls' if os.name=='nt' else 'clear')
def title():
    print("___  ___                                        \n|  \/  |                                        \n| .  . | ___   ___  _ __                        \n| |\/| |/ _ \ / _ \| '_ \                       \n| |  | | (_) | (_) | | | |                      \n\_|  |_/\___/ \___/|_| |_|                      \n                                                \n                                                \n _                     _ _                      \n| |                   | (_)                     \n| |     __ _ _ __   __| |_ _ __   __ _          \n| |    / _` | '_ \ / _` | | '_ \ / _` |         \n| |___| (_| | | | | (_| | | | | | (_| |         \n\_____/\__,_|_| |_|\__,_|_|_| |_|\__, |         \n                                  __/ |         \n                                 |___/          \n _____                    _ _ _   _             \n|  ___|                  | (_) | (_)            \n| |____  ___ __   ___  __| |_| |_ _  ___  _ __  \n|  __\ \/ / '_ \ / _ \/ _` | | __| |/ _ \| '_ \ \n| |___>  <| |_) |  __/ (_| | | |_| | (_) | | | |\n\____/_/\_\ .__/ \___|\__,_|_|\__|_|\___/|_| |_|\n          | |                                   \n          |_|                                   \n")
def setup():
    global name
    global HP
    global SP
    global OP
    while True:
        name = input('What is your name --->   ')
        isnum = False
        for i in name:
            if i.isnumeric():
                isnum = True
                break
    
        if isnum:
            print('Please type your name.  ')
            continue
    
        break
    
    HP = randint(17,20)
    SP = randint(17,20)
    OP = randint(90,100)
    print('welcome ['+name+':]:  to the moon landing expedition')

def villager():
    global npcname
    global response
    responses = ['hello', 'who are you?', 'why are you here?', 'what are your intentions?']
    npcnamechoice = ['Sarah', 'Bobby', 'Chris', 'Trent', 'Susan', 'Michelle', 'Mara']
    shuffle(npcnamechoice)
    print('\n['+npcname+':]Hello my name is'+npcname+'would you like to talk to me?\n')
    shuffle(responses)
    print('press y to talk to the villager')
    if input().upper== 'Y':
        print('['+npcname+':]  '+responses[0])
    else:
        print('['+npcname+':] Goodbye')
def enemy():
    global enemyHP
    global enemyMP
    global enemyname
    enemyHP = randint(5,20)
    enemyMP = randint(5,20)
    enemyname = ['Space ogre', 'Space witch', 'Space bandit', 'Rick Astley in Space', 'Emminem In space']
    shuffle(enemyname)
    print('\nSuddenly you hear somthing in the woods and a'+enemyname[0]+'appears')
    print('your enemy has'+' '+ str(enemyHP)+' '+'Health points')
    print('your enemy has'+' '+ str(enemyMP)+' '+'magic points')
def north():
    global gonorth
    gonorth = 'you have decided to head north'
def east():
    global goeast
    goeast='you have decided to go east'
def west():
    global gowest
    gowest = 'you have decided to go west'
clear_screen()
title()
setup()
print('hello this game is created by ',__Author__)
print('your health is at ', HP, 'your stamina points are at', SP, 'your Oxygen levels at the start of Chapter one wil be ', OP)
print('<suspencful music activates>, Robotic voice:"hello and welcome to the',)
title()
input('press enter to continue')
print('you have been choosen out of fifty-million canidates for this once in a lifetime adventure your mission...\nis reconasance of planets near and far, my superiors have trust in you\nplease do your be..."<electrical static cuts out the automated voice>\n<emergency sirens are sounded>\nMan on Intercoms:"this is not a drill i repeat this is not a drill everyone you must evacuate imediat..."')
print('<the sound of gunshots can be heard all around you> *in mind:even though i fear for my life, i feel like aslong as i stay put i am safe*<a loud buzzer is heard>\nAutomated voice:"Initiating emergancy launch in T-minus ten')
print('nine')
print('eight')
print('seven')
print('six')
print('five')
print('four')
print('t-h-r-e-e-e-e-e')
print('t-t-t-t-w-o-o-o')
print('o-o-o-o-n-n-n-e-e')
print('i-i-i-g-n-i-i-i-s-i-o-n"')
print('<the sound of rocket thrusters are all you are able to hear as you watch the ground getting fartehr way>')
print('\n\n\n\n\n\n\n<five years have passed since the attack on the military space center>\n<your space craft has almost completly run out of fuel>\n<you are forced to make an emergancy landing on one of the moons of the planet nexus>')
input('press enter to start the first chapter of the game')
print(" _____ _                 _            \n/  __ \ |               | |           \n| /  \/ |__   __ _ _ __ | |_ ___ _ __ \n| |   | '_ \ / _` | '_ \| __/ _ \ '__|\n| \__/\ | | | (_| | |_) | ||  __/ |   \n \____/_| |_|\__,_| .__/ \__\___|_|   \n                  | |                 \n                  |_|                 \n _____                                \n|  _  |                               \n| | | |_ __   ___                     \n| | | | '_ \ / _ \                    \n\ \_/ / | | |  __/                    \n \___/|_| |_|\___|                    \n                                      \n                                      \n _____ _      _   _                   \n/  ___(_)    | | | |                  \n\ `--. ___  _| |_| |__                \n `--. \ \ \/ / __| '_ \               \n/\__/ / |>  <| |_| | | |              \n\____/|_/_/\_\\__|_| |_|              \n                                      \n                                      \n___  ___                              \n|  \/  |                              \n| .  . | ___   ___  _ __              \n| |\/| |/ _ \ / _ \| '_ \             \n| |  | | (_) | (_) | | | |            \n\_|  |_/\___/ \___/|_| |_|            \n                                      \n                                      \n _____  __                            \n|  _  |/ _|                           \n| | | | |_                            \n| | | |  _|                           \n\ \_/ / |                             \n \___/|_|                             \n                                      \n                                      \n _   _                                \n| \ | |                               \n|  \| | _____  ___   _ ___            \n| . ` |/ _ \ \/ / | | / __|              \n| |\  |  __/>  <| |_| \__ \              \n\_| \_/\___/_/\_\\__,_|___/              \n                                         \n                                 ")

input('press enter to continue')


print(name+']:"Ok so i am here on one of the moons on an unknown planet with absolutly no way of contacting for help i have no fuel and my power reserves are failing,\n soon i will have no oxygen left,\n fortunatly there are solar panels on the side of the rocket so once the sun hits the panels the oxygen production systems will kick in,\ni just hope i can survive long enough for a search party comes to find me."')
print('the sixth moon of nexus is the biggest source of metal in the universe, (dont wory about oxygen for the time being ')
```

Comment: the tkinter isnt yet implemented for gui im currently working out of cmd

Answer (score 0):

I would consolidate all input together and do it there. Essentially, after every action, print the stats along with the input.

Separately, this would work better as a class. That way you can share data without using globals.

If you want to get really fancy, you can use a [status bar](https://python-enlighten.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#enlighten.Manager.status_bar) and [progress bars](https://python-enlighten.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#enlighten.Counter) for player levels from [Enlighten](https://python-enlighten.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html).

Edit: Here is a possible implementation using classes. Here oxygen is a property, so it is calculated every time it is called. You may want to delay setting the start time for oxygen until the intro is done, or pad that number by adding 5 - 10 seconds. It's also rounding to an int, but you may want to use a float so you can have 3.6 vs rounding to 4.

You may also want to divide this up and make seperate classes for the main player, villagers, enemies, etc.

```
__Author__ = 'Mangle200/Tristan Lauzon'
import os
import random
import time


class MoonLandingExpedition:

    def __init__(self):

        self.health = 0
        self.stamina = 0
        self._oxygen_start = (0, 0.0)
        self.name = None
        self.direction = None

    @property
    def oxygen(self):

        oxygen_per_sec = 0.33
        initial_level, initial_time = self._oxygen_start
        time_delta = time.time() - initial_time
        current_level = max(0, initial_level - time_delta * oxygen_per_sec)
        return round(current_level)

    def clear_screen(self):
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

    def encounter_enemy(self):

        e_name = random.choice(('Space ogre', 'Space witch', 'Space bandit',
                              'Rick Astley in Space', 'Emminem In space'))
        e_health = random.randint(5, 20)
        e_magic = random.randint(5, 20)

        print('\nSuddenly you hear somthing in the woods and a {e_name} appears')
        print('your enemy has {e_health} Health points')
        print('your enemy has {e_magic} magic points')

    def encounter_villager(self):

        v_name = random.choice(('Sarah', 'Bobby', 'Chris', 'Trent', 'Susan', 'Michelle', 'Mara'))
        responses = ('Hello!', 'Who are you?', 'Why are you here?', 'What are your intentions?')

        print(f'\n[{v_name}:] Hello my name is {v_name} would you like to talk to me?\n')
        if self.get_input('Press y to talk to the villager').upper == 'Y':
            print(f'[{v_name}:] {random.choice(responses)}')
        else:
            print(f'[{v_name}:] Goodbye')

    def get_name(self):

        while True:
            name = input('What is your name? --->   ')
            if any(char.isdigit() for char in name):
                print('Please type your name.  ')
            else:
                break

        return name

    def get_input(self, message):
        self.print_status()
        return input(message)

    def intro(self):

        print("You have been chosen...")
        print("Moon of Nexus")
        self.get_input('press enter to continue')

    def print_status(self):
        print(f'Health: {self.health}  Stamina: {self.stamina}  Oxygen: {self.oxygen}')

    def run(self):

        self.clear_screen()
        self.title()
        self.setup()
        print('hello this game is created by ',__Author__)
        self.print_status()
        print('<suspenseful music activates>, Robotic voice:"hello and welcome to the',)
        self.title()
        input('press enter to continue')
        self.intro()

    def setup(self):

        self.health = random.randint(17, 20)
        self.stamina = random.randint(17, 20)
        self._oxygen_start = (random.randint(17, 20), time.time())

        self.name = self.get_name()

        print(f'Welcome [{self.name}:]:  to the moon landing expedition')

    def title(self):
        print("Moon Landing Expedition")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    game = MoonLandingExpedition()
    game.run()
```

Comment: how do i implement this in my code without ruining the base code?

Comment: also when i try to import enlighten it says its unable to import it

Comment: You can reuse most of the code, just restructure it.
Enlighten is not part of the standard library, you'd have to install it. Consister that a stretch goal :-)

Comment: Added an example in the response

Comment: ok thank you for the help i will see if this works for me otherwise ill just have the oxygen as a static value then change that value once a condition is met